# Add a second image on an img64 background jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, base64, jspdf

I am making a business card generator.

I've made a basic form that restricts the text on an img64 background.
So far so good.

But I would like the person to be able to add a profile picture on the card.

So I made a button for the user to upload their own photo, but I can't add it to the pdf.

So my goal is to be able to superimpose an image over the background of the business card.

If anyone can help me?

*Here is my code:*

```js
   //UPLOAD IMAGE PROFILE

  var imageFile = document.getElementById("imageFile")

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")

  var button = document.getElementById('button')

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

  imageFile.addEventListener("change", handleImage, false)

  function handleImage(e) {
    console.log(e)

    var reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = function(event){

      var image = new Image()

      image.onload = function(){
        canvas.width = image.width
        canvas.height = image.height
        ctx.drawImage(image,0,0)
      }

      image.src = event.target.result

    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])

  }

   
   //jsPDF

  $('#button').click(function() {


     var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'in', [88,58]);
     
     var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ........
     
     doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG',0,0,88,58);


      var nom = $('#nom').val();
      var tel = $('#tel').val();
      var email = $('#email').val();
      var rsac = $('#rsac').val();

      doc.setFontSize(200);
      doc.setTextColor(126, 127, 127);

      doc.text(6, 25, nom);
      doc.text(6, 29, tel);
      doc.text(6, 33, email);
      doc.text(65, 40, rsac);
     doc.save('test.pdf');

  });
```

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js" integrity="sha512-s/XK4vYVXTGeUSv4bRPOuxSDmDlTedEpMEcAQk0t/FMd9V6ft8iXdwSBxV0eD60c6w/tjotSlKu9J2AAW1ckTA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar"><h1>Générateur de carte de visite</h1></div>
<div id="wrapper">

    <input type="text" id="nom" value=""/ placeholder="Nom Prenom"><br>
    <input type="text" id="tel" value="" placeholder="Telephone" /><br>
    <input type="text" id="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail" /><br>
    <input type="text" id="rsac" value="" placeholder="N°RSAC"/><br>

    <label for="imagefile">Choose a profile picture:</label><br>

    <input type="file" id="imageFile"><br>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <button id="button"> Telecharger pdf</button>
    
    
    
</body>
</html>
```